# Excel data to a Raster Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, cartography, excel

I am trying to create a radiometric map, I have x, y , z coordinates and a value in excel. I want to create a raster map based on this data. How do I go about doing this. I am using ArcGIS 10 with Target/

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old post but what to do if the points are already in a regular grid with only the altitude value ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are interested in interpolating the data into a raster (unless the points are already in a regular grid).

You should import your data into ArcMap as a points layer using the add x/y data tool. Then you can interpolate the points into a raster using your z value with the IDW interpolation with [spatial analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/IDW/009z0000006m000000/).

There are [other interpolation methods](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Interpolation_tools/009z00000069000000/) worth considering, but IDW is the simplest.